# How to crop bounding boxes for multiple objects using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv for cropping objects using the bounding boxes. The code does not work when there are multiple boxes for one image. The bounding box info is saved in a csv file. For instance, there two objects need to be cropped form the same image but different bounding boxes.

```
Camera4_03-22-18_15-01.png  647 785 1533 1148   LUT-170
Camera4_03-22-18_15-01.png -442 852 339 1257    LUT-170

My code is:

df = pd.read_csv("Camera_1.csv")

img_list = df['Name'].tolist()
x_min = df['x_min'].tolist()
x_max = df['x_max'].tolist()
y_min = df['y_min'].tolist()
y_max = df['y_max'].tolist()
labels = df['Labels'].tolist()


for i in range(len(df)): 
    img = cv2.imread(img_list[i])   
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x_min[i],y_min[i]), (x_max[i],y_max[i]), (0,255,0),2) 
    cropped_img = img[ y_min[i]:y_max[i], x_min[i]:x_max[i]]

The error is:

---> 33     cv2.imwrite(labels[i]+'labels_{}.png'.format(i), cropped_img)
     34 
     35 

error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-req-build-afu9cjzs/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:803: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Comment: Your image is empty. Apparently your crop coordinates are in error. You should print your x,y min and max values to be sure you are getting good values as expected from your csv.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the crop coordinate was wrong. Once I deleted it, everything was fine. Can I write few lines of code, which will tell the program to go the next file instead of stopping the code and throwing an error?